# Why volatile keyword does not help, given that it provides properly read and write to shared variables

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

This is my simple class which increments a shared variable in a separate thread:

```
public class Main {

    private volatile int count;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.doJob();

    }

    private void doJob() {
        Runnable runnable1 = () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                incrementCount();
            }
        };

        Runnable runnable2 = () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                incrementCount();
            }
        };

        Thread t1 = new Thread(runnable1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(runnable2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("------------------ count is : " + count);
    }

    private void incrementCount() {
        count = count + 1;
    }
}
```

Now can anybody tell me why can't `volatile` keyword help me produce correct results, which I expect to be 20000?

But when I change the method declaration to `private syncronized void incrementCount()`, everything goes as expected, it prints 20000 without even `volatile` keyword.

Comment: @dev8080 `volatile` has nothing to do with serialization. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4

Comment: @dev8080 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.2 they behave quite differently when accessed concurrently

Comment: Apologies for my wrong comment.

Answer (score 7):

The point is that statement

```
count = count + 1;
```

is not an atomic operation. So two threads can view the same old value of count variable and then calculate new value. Even more one thread can do several cycles of calculation between another thread reading and writing.

Comment: Dr. Bogdan, but what about the fact that by setting the variable volatile, we solve the visibility problem, and in this case each thread can see the latest result, meaning that it can see already incremented count, yes?

Comment: The fact that it is visible doesn't mean you cannot have a race condition. If two threads operate the exact same code at the exact same time (which these days, with multiple cores being standard is quite possible) they would fetch the same value, increment it at the same time, and write it back at the same time. That way, it would increase by 1, even though it should have increased by 2. In cases like these, it's better to use `AtomicInteger`.

Answer (score 6):

The `volatile` keyword guarantees visibility.

Where as `synchronized` guarantees mutual exclusivity .

What that means is that when a variable is marked as `volatile` all the threads will have to access to the latest value. It is not cached. Think of a multi core/multi processor machine and each having its own cache. With `volatile` each time a thread reads the value of the variable it is guaranteed to be the latest and greatest.

Where as in the same scenario, each thread can update it.

Now in your case `count = count + 1`, there are multiple operations happening.

Read value of `count`, increment it and then set to back as value of variable `count`.

In this if `count` is `volatile` and say at time `t` thread 1 updates it, to say 1. 
Then at `t+1` say thread 2 and thread 3 want to update it, volatile guarantees that both of these threads see the value 1. 
However both will increment it by 1 and set it back. So you have effectively lost one increment.

What `synchronized` guarantees is that at `t+1`, only one of these threads say thread 2 is going to enter it, read the value 1, increment it to 2, and set it back to the variable count. And then thread 3 can enter this synchronized block of code to read the value which is 2, increment it to 3, and set it back to `count`

Comment: In that case please note here any scenario when the volatile can help, without additional syncronized keyword.

Comment: @HaykMkhitaryan simplest example: you want a thread to stop looping. You can do that by checking the value of a boolean flag at each iteration, and by setting this boolean flag when the loop must stop. Or, you have only one thread modifying a variable, but you want all the other threads to see the latest value.

Answer (score 0):

> what about the fact that by setting the variable volatile, we solve the visibility problem, and in this case each thread can see the latest result, meaning that it can see already incremented count, yes?

That's not enough.  Here's what can happen:

```
t1 thread                                    t2 thread
---------                                    ---------
Enter incrementCount()                       Enter incrementCount()
fetch count from memory (count==702)         fetch count from memory (count = 702)
compute new value, 703,                      swapped out
store new value into count
...
calls incrementCount() 1000 more times
...                                     
fetch count from memory (count==1703)
compute new value ,1704                      swapped back in
store new value into count                   compute new value, 703
Enter incrementCount()                       store new value into count
fetch count from memory (count==703)         ...
...
```

You can use `synchronized` to turn the fetch, the add, and the store into a single atomic operation.  As a side benefit, you no longer need to make `count` volatile.

```
private Object lock = new Object();
private int count;
...
private void incrementCount() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        count = count + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that this has not been suggested yet, but this is a good scenario to use [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

To repeat what other answers have stated, the problem lies with addition and assignment being a compound operation. 2 or more additions that should be independent of another may become interleaved, resulting in only a single increment that should have been however many that should have occurred because a new value is not assigned before another thread reads the old value and increments that instead.